Can't open LUKS encrypted drive anymore
I'm running unraid and I'm running a pool of two mirrored NVME drives. I lost power and the setup of the pool got messed up. They are encrypted with LUKS2 but they aren't recognized by LUKS any more.
running:
cryptsetup --debug luksDump /dev/nvme0n1 outputs: 

results in:
# cryptsetup 2.6.1 processing "cryptsetup --debug luksDump /dev/nvme1n1"
# Verifying parameters for command luksDump.
# Running command luksDump.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating context for crypt device /dev/nvme1n1.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/nvme1n1 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load any crypt type from device /dev/nvme1n1.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 1.1.1v  1 Aug 2023) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.6.1.
# Detected kernel Linux 6.1.106-Unraid x86_64.
# Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme1n1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:0
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme1n1.
# Device /dev/nvme1n1 READ lock taken.
# Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
# Opening locked device /dev/nvme1n1
# Verifying locked device handle (bdev)
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x8000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x10000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x20000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x40000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x80000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x100000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x200000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x400000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme1n1
# LUKS2 header read failed (-22).
# Device /dev/nvme1n1 READ lock released.
Device /dev/nvme1n1 is not a valid LUKS device.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/nvme1n1 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Closing read only fd for /dev/nvme1n1.
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).

running:
cryptsetup repair /dev/nvme1n1

outputs:
WARNING!
========
Really try to repair LUKS device header?

Are you sure? (Type 'yes' in capital letters): YES
Device /dev/nvme1n1 is not a valid LUKS device.

Since this was a failed I checked if I can somehow restore the LUKS headers and found the excelent post from frostschutz where he explains step by step how to restore a damaged LUKS header.
He's saying to run:
stdbuf -oL strings -n 64 -t d /dev/nvme1n1 | grep '"keyslots":'

which outputs one line (or header?) for him.
But for me it outputs two (different positions), I don't know if this is because he has only one key or if this is because my header is messed up differently. This happens for both drives, mirror and main drive (stdbuf -oL strings -n 64 -t d /dev/nvme0n1 | grep '"keyslots":'), probably due to the fact, that after restart I mixed up the mirror and the main drive (but not sure here).
Here is the output for nvme1n1:
1052672 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":9,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"z4H0Iq9TrpZcnUa0DtehStHFoW0+tn0wPDfPzu1ytYU="}},"1":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"290816","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"eAcf0NDPEUY+y10JSDFrghRuU5BJI+SACxvaa5NU6l8="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0","1"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":427641,"salt":"K9wWAAswdntXvDPo8RhDj+S+tWixXk/tIeGBRVvVTIc=","digest":"YiHlLN1F4OofwYq6skL5yznpVo7KTrcMMfNM75IHYDw="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}
1069056 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":9,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"z4H0Iq9TrpZcnUa0DtehStHFoW0+tn0wPDfPzu1ytYU="}},"1":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"290816","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"eAcf0NDPEUY+y10JSDFrghRuU5BJI+SACxvaa5NU6l8="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0","1"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":427641,"salt":"K9wWAAswdntXvDPo8RhDj+S+tWixXk/tIeGBRVvVTIc=","digest":"YiHlLN1F4OofwYq6skL5yznpVo7KTrcMMfNM75IHYDw="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}

and here for nvme0n1:
1052672 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"uiAnxes9fKDn/PrBIdX/fMkuxVIHVPY/taPFAr3wUQg="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":462335,"salt":"pp7o6+NeKcqypapbs1/wdLt4EVBhAcrCyheHRJkxcpQ=","digest":"8ns2TTxoFvXhlYftWpxe4Gzg3Jt7usx4wlVk8NMc8Ek="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}
1069056 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"uiAnxes9fKDn/PrBIdX/fMkuxVIHVPY/taPFAr3wUQg="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":462335,"salt":"pp7o6+NeKcqypapbs1/wdLt4EVBhAcrCyheHRJkxcpQ=","digest":"8ns2TTxoFvXhlYftWpxe4Gzg3Jt7usx4wlVk8NMc8Ek="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}

so I did:
partition=1032192
offset=32768
size=258048
sudo dd bs=1 skip=$((partition+offset)) count=$((size)) if=/dev/nvme1n1 of=header.$((offset))
gzip < header.32768 > header.32768.gz

partition=1032192
offset=290816
size=258048
sudo dd bs=1 skip=$((partition+offset)) count=$((size)) if=/dev/nvme1n1 of=header.$((offset))
gzip < header.290816 > header.290816.gz

dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=32768 if=header.32768 of=luks.recovery
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=290816 if=header.290816 of=luks.recovery

stat -c %s header.* shows, that it's not compressible, so it should be good.
Next steps are creating the recovery image, where I add one difference, I do 100M, since 16M always gave me the error Device luks.recovery is too small for activation, there is no remaining space for data.:
truncate -s 100M luks.recovery
cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 luks.recovery #confirm with YES, just hit enter when it asks for a password (but also tried a password)
cryptsetup luksErase luks.recovery #confirm with YES

I run:
printf "%s\0" "$(jq -c < header.json)" |
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=4096 of=luks.recovery
printf "%s\0" "$(jq -c < header.json)" |
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=20480 of=luks.recovery

dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=32768 if=header.32768 of=luks.recovery
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=290816 if=header.290816 of=luks.recovery

cryptsetup luksDump --debug luks.recovery
...
# Checksum:a752d7cd864edfa1dda44707c658bd399f23b3620df0d9ee575f7a0f1dd788f6 (on-disk)
# Checksum:4acb91e5cccefefa38bf18ac959cda0d8b962cc57c0dc12a2671108883deec94 (in-memory)
# LUKS2 header checksum error (offset 0).
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device luks.recovery
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:7fd54c2f9bd8867b222aa716adf8961485cf92060f6a9b132cbf1bf58dea9409 (on-disk)
# Checksum:f23e1b5f4197a51148ab6a69fd22d3b3c2f5ed912f259e71d773c9348ec98477 (in-memory)
# LUKS2 header checksum error (offset 16384).
...

So I do:
echo a752d7cd864edfa1dda44707c658bd399f23b3620df0d9ee575f7a0f1dd788f6 | xxd -r -p | hexdump -C
echo 4acb91e5cccefefa38bf18ac959cda0d8b962cc57c0dc12a2671108883deec94 | xxd -r -p | hexdump -C
echo 7fd54c2f9bd8867b222aa716adf8961485cf92060f6a9b132cbf1bf58dea9409 | xxd -r -p | hexdump -C
echo f23e1b5f4197a51148ab6a69fd22d3b3c2f5ed912f259e71d773c9348ec98477 | xxd -r -p | hexdump -C

exdump -C luks.recovery | grep 'a7 52 d7 cd 86 4e'' returns:
000001c0  a7 52 d7 cd 86 4e df a1  dd a4 47 07 c6 58 bd 39  |.R...N....G..X.9|

So I run:
echo 4acb91e5cccefefa38bf18ac959cda0d8b962cc57c0dc12a2671108883deec94 |
xxd -r -p |
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$((0x000001c0)) of=luks.recovery

Now the same thing for the second key hexdump -C luks.recovery | grep '7f d5 4c 2f 9b d8' which returns:
000041c0  7f d5 4c 2f 9b d8 86 7b  22 2a a7 16 ad f8 96 14  |..L/...{"*......|

resulting command out of this:
echo f23e1b5f4197a51148ab6a69fd22d3b3c2f5ed912f259e71d773c9348ec98477 |
xxd -r -p |
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$((0x000041c0)) of=luks.recovery

so next steps are straight forward again:
cryptsetup repair luks.recovery
cryptsetup luksDump luks.recovery
which outputs:
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          4
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           961d61c5-9ac6-4e09-b892-97617142c5ec
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)
Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2id
    Time cost:  9
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       cf 81 f4 22 af 53 ae 96 5c 9d 46 b4 0e d7 a1 4a 
                d1 c5 a1 6d 3e b6 7d 30 3c 37 cf ce ed 72 b5 85 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
  1: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2id
    Time cost:  10
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       78 07 1f d0 d0 cf 11 46 3e cb 5d 09 48 31 6b 82 
                14 6e 53 90 49 23 e4 80 0b 1b da 6b 93 54 ea 5f 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:290816 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 427641
    Salt:       2b dc 16 00 0b 30 76 7b 57 bc 33 e8 f1 18 43 8f 
                e4 be b5 68 b1 5e 4f ed 21 e1 81 45 5b d5 4c 87 
    Digest:     62 21 e5 2c dd 45 e0 ea 1f c1 8a ba b2 42 f9 cb 
                39 e9 56 8e ca 4e b7 0c 31 f3 4c ef 92 07 60 3c

Now just to try, I run:
sudo losetup --find --show --read-only --offset 1032192 /dev/nvme1n1
sudo cryptsetup open --readonly --header luks.recovery /dev/loop21 luksrecovery #input password
sudo cryptsetup open --readonly --header luks.recovery /dev/loop21 luksrecovery --key-file $keyfilepath

which returns for both open commands No key available with this passphrase..
Out of curiosity I ran sudo stdbuf -oL strings -n 64 -t d luks.recovery | grep '"keyslots":' which now returns even 3 headers:
4096 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":9,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"z4H0Iq9TrpZcnUa0DtehStHFoW0+tn0wPDfPzu1ytYU="}},"1":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"290816","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"eAcf0NDPEUY+y10JSDFrghRuU5BJI+SACxvaa5NU6l8="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0","1"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":427641,"salt":"K9wWAAswdntXvDPo8RhDj+S+tWixXk/tIeGBRVvVTIc=","digest":"YiHlLN1F4OofwYq6skL5yznpVo7KTrcMMfNM75IHYDw="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}
20480 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":9,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"z4H0Iq9TrpZcnUa0DtehStHFoW0+tn0wPDfPzu1ytYU="}},"1":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"290816","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"eAcf0NDPEUY+y10JSDFrghRuU5BJI+SACxvaa5NU6l8="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0","1"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":427641,"salt":"K9wWAAswdntXvDPo8RhDj+S+tWixXk/tIeGBRVvVTIc=","digest":"YiHlLN1F4OofwYq6skL5yznpVo7KTrcMMfNM75IHYDw="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}
36864 {"keyslots":{"0":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"32768","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":9,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"z4H0Iq9TrpZcnUa0DtehStHFoW0+tn0wPDfPzu1ytYU="}},"1":{"type":"luks2","key_size":64,"af":{"type":"luks1","stripes":4000,"hash":"sha256"},"area":{"type":"raw","offset":"290816","size":"258048","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","key_size":64},"kdf":{"type":"argon2id","time":10,"memory":1048576,"cpus":4,"salt":"eAcf0NDPEUY+y10JSDFrghRuU5BJI+SACxvaa5NU6l8="}}},"tokens":{},"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","size":"dynamic","iv_tweak":"0","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}},"digests":{"0":{"type":"pbkdf2","keyslots":["0","1"],"segments":["0"],"hash":"sha256","iterations":427641,"salt":"K9wWAAswdntXvDPo8RhDj+S+tWixXk/tIeGBRVvVTIc=","digest":"YiHlLN1F4OofwYq6skL5yznpVo7KTrcMMfNM75IHYDw="}},"config":{"json_size":"12288","keyslots_size":"16744448"}}

output of cat /proc/partitions:
   major minor  #blocks  name

   7        0    2649764 loop0
   7        1     484580 loop1
   7        2     148272 loop2
   7        3      11996 loop3
   7        4     278508 loop4
   7        5      76028 loop5
   7        6      91840 loop6
   7        7      10976 loop7
 259        0 1953514584 nvme0n1
 259        1 1953514584 nvme1n1
   8        0  488386584 sda
   8        1  488385560 sda1
   8       16 17578328064 sdb
   8       17 17578328015 sdb1
   8       32 11718885376 sdc
   8       33 11718885327 sdc1
   8       48  117220824 sdd
   8       49  117219800 sdd1
   8       64 11718885376 sde
   8       65 11718885327 sde1
   8       80 11718885376 sdf
   8       81 11718885327 sdf1
   8       96  125042688 sdg
   8       97   19135456 sdg1
   8       98  105906181 sdg2
   7        8     517212 loop8
   7        9          4 loop9
   7       10      14324 loop10
   7       11     153468 loop11
   7       12     108924 loop12
   7       13      10924 loop13
   7       14        564 loop14
   7       15      39760 loop15
   7       16 1953513560 loop16

Luckily I've got a backup, but it's not up to date (most of it is would be loose only a night or so, but some is probably some days old) and I'd like to prevent data loss if possible.
Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this?
What I find Interesting and doesn't make too much sense to me:

Why are there two headers for me, but at least this is consistent with the undamaged drives
The Partition offsets for the first and second header are overlapping at 1048576

1052672−4096=1048576=0.125MiB
1052672−20480=1032192=0.123046875MiB
1069056−4096=1064960=0.126953125MiB
1069056−20480=1048576=0.125MiB


Why does the recovery file now have even 3 headers?


If the drives are a mirrored pair, don't read the underlying halves directly, but instead get the mirror running and LUKS unlock that

It's the same for both drives, I checked already if I could get the mirror running, but this didn't work as well. Will add this information into my post.

Maybe something corrupted your partition table, or maybe you're just using the wrong device. Check cat /proc/partitions. Do you not have a nvme1n1p1? Should be at offset 1 MiB.

"I checked already if I could get the mirror running, but this didn't work as well" - when you [edit] your post please remember to explain what "this didn't work" actually involved.

I added the information about /proc/partitions in the main post. There is no nvme1n1p1 but this doesn't exist for any drive I've got.
Also, I adapted the post, to explain, that the behavior is for both disks the same for the output of stdbuf -oL strings -n 64 -t d /dev/nvme1n1 | grep '"keyslots":'

So, no partitions for some reason... wiped? Changed the sector size?? Try losetup with 1MiB offset (losetup example the linked answer)

It took me a while to come to the realization, that I completely forgot to add both keys with echo key |  xxd -r -p | dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$((0x000001c0)) of=luks.recovery.
Now I'm at least getting "No key available with this passphrase."
losetup with 1MiB offset didn't work as well, that's when I started realizing what might be going on. I will now try it with a partition offset of 1032192

Now, I ran some more tests, and it added some more questions. I added all the information into the post, it's a full run down of what I'm doing (at least for one partition offset, the other is the same).

try 1048576 (1 MiB) instead of 1032192 - if that does not work then maybe more than just the partition table was corrupted. Impossible for me to judge remotely...

1MiB for losetup, correct? Not for the other parts, when doing it only for the losetup part, I'm still getting the no key message.

Can I reuse the header of another disk with an intact header if they share the same keys/passwords? I've got other disks which are encrypted with the same keys. But persumably not, since they don't have the same salt, correct?

Another Idea, can I backup the whole header in it's current state and instead write the header of the lucks.recovery file write it to the actual drive? That way I could test if it decrypts with the default tools which are given in unraid. I feel like this is an error cause, and if I can't access the data anyways I can give it a shot before I wipe the drive and accept my losses.
